# RPM 4.8.0 and 'Prereq'

Tags: rpm

I am trying to install a large set of very old packages with rpm 4.8.0, and the transaction order is resulting in an installation failure.

Specifically,

- I have a package (tzdata) that says: Prereq: /bin/cp
- '/bin/cp' is in 'coreutils'

Yet 'coreutils' is still *after* tzdata in the installation order.

Looking at the source (rpm 4.8.0) I can see that the design in this area has changed a lot but it *seems* like the intent is that the old 'Prereq' flag is still supported.

```
/* map legacy prereq to pre/preun as needed */
if (isLegacyPreReq(dsflags)) {
    flags |= (teType == TR_ADDED) ?
             RPMSENSE_SCRIPT_PRE : RPMSENSE_SCRIPT_PREUN;
}
```

Does that sound right?

Based on the code comments, I also get a strong sense that provide/require relationships will sometimes be ignored in order to eliminate dependency loops.  I would like to know if/when this is happening, but it doesn't seem like there are any messages emitted, even at debug level, for such an event ('dropping' a relationship).

Can anyone suggest how to generate and/or interpret debug information in the transaction output to understand why this particular ordering clue is not observed?

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/deryni/30afd029c30de0f04377) python script should (assuming it works correctly on 4.8.0 I wrote it against 4.4.2.2) show you the pre-reqs for the package you put on the command line. Change the loop at the bottom to print all the pre-reqs. Not sure if that'll help or not though. (I'm sort of astonished that packages as old as you claim can install correctly at all.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in rpm-4.8.0 has chosen to remap Prereq: (which tries
to force a package installation before current package) as if
it were a Requires(pre): (which marks a require dependency needed
by a %pre scriptlet)contrary to what was originally implemented in rpm.

Yes: dependency loops will be dealt with "best effort" so that an
installation doesn't halt with dependency loops. One crude way to handle loops is to
discard all dependencies in a loop. Another, better, way yo handle loops is to attempt to
install all packages in the loop as a single entity. In both cases
the order determined by the dependencies in a loop is indeterminate and issues
like you are reporting can/will happen.

Installing with rpm -Uvv displays LOOP messages for all dependencies
that are ignored. Verify whether you have a LOOP that includes packages
involved with installing tzdata.

Meanwhile, using 2 transactions to guarantee the installation of a known prerequisite,
or using a hand crafted/ordered package manifest with --nodeps/--noorder during the installation, is
likely going to be your best work around to packaging flaw(s) and a change
in the semantics/implementation of Prereq: in rpm.